# How do I map <CTRL-R> to be used by vim in Pycharm

Tags: vim, pycharm, ideavim

I have a simple but annoying problem. I want to be able to use the CTRL-R vim command in Pycharm with the IdeaVim plugin. However, Pycharm uses that to do its own run command.

So I tried removing the mapping for Pycharm for CTRL-R, now I want to map it to Vim but when I go to keymap I cannot see any mapping available

Anyone have any solution, maybe remapping to another key combination?

## EDIT

As per @Andrey's suggestion, I checked the vim emulation settings and no  option, please see the screenshot below. Could this perhaps be done in the .ideavimrc file like remap to another key combination

[PYCHARM SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bOgJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

IdeaVim doesn't use "Settings | Keymap". It tries to install its own key handlers for Vim shortcuts. If there are any conflicts between the IDE keymap and the IdeaVim keymap, they are shown in "Settings | Other | Vim Emulation". For any shortctut there you can choose either the IDE handler or the Vim handler.